# What's the value of the $\frac{AT}{TC}$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In triangle $ABC$, a circle is drawn by $B$
> which is tangent to $AC$ at point $T$. This circle intersects $AB$ and $BC$ at points "$R$" and "$S$" respectively.
> If $4RB = 3BS$ and $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{RT} = \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{TS}$, calculate $\frac{AT}{TC}$. (Answer:$\frac{3}{4}$)

My progress: I couldn't "develop" this..

only that $OR=OT=OS = r\\\triangle ORT \cong \triangle OTS\ (S.A.S.)$

[image]

(figure without scale)

Comment: Is $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{RT} = \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{TS}$ ?

Comment: You should share your attempt. The question comes across more or less as asking someone else to solve your problem which is not encouraged on the site. But given we have spent so much time together on the site that I know you always make efforts. Just figure a way out to articulate your effort.

Comment: Hint: $BT$ is angle bisector of $\angle B$

Comment: @Aqua looking at the diagram and subtended angle at the center, I think OP wanted to say arc $RT$ and $TS$ are equal. If the arcs are equal, they would subtend the same angle at point $B$ on the circle.

Comment: $TR=TS\rightarrow\angle ABT=\angle CBT\rightarrow m/n=c/a$. Bisector theorem.

Comment: OK I was expecting you to revert based on my earlier hint but you did not :) I have a very easy solution to this. Just notice that $RS \parallel AC$ as $OT$ is perp to both. So along with my earlier hint, $AT:TC = 3:4$. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: @MathLover  I know this website guideline but I really got stuck in this exercise. I always try to develop a path and relationships in order to reach a solution. My apologies but it was not intentional not to develop the question...

Comment: @petaarantes yes I know for sure it is not intentional. My point is that sometimes if you do not make headway, at least mention what different paths you tried and why it reached a dead-end. By the way, did you understand my solution? In my mind, it is the shortest solution.

Comment: @MathLover  I didn't quite understand. Where does RS∥AC  come from?

Comment: $ RS \perp OT$, are you with me?

Comment: $ \triangle ORS$ is isosceles with $OR = OS$ and angle bisector of $\angle ROS$ will be perpendicular to side $RS$.

Comment: @MathLover  now I visualized... grateful

Comment: yes so as $OT$ is perp to both $RS$ and $AB$, they must be parallel leading to $AT/TC = BA/BC = BR/BS = 3/4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the tangent and secant theorem we have:

$$AT^2=AR\cdot AB, \quad CT^2 = CS\cdot BC.$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{AT^2}{CT^2}=\frac{AR\cdot AB}{CS\cdot BC}.$$

On the other hand, we know that $BT$ is bissector of $\angle ABC$, then

$$\frac{AT^2}{CT^2}=\frac{AB^2}{BC^2}.$$

So, we got that

$$\frac{AR}{SC}=\frac{AR+RB}{CS+SB} \, \Longleftrightarrow \, SC\cdot AR + RB\cdot CS =AR\cdot SC +AR\cdot SB \, \Longleftrightarrow \, RB\cdot CS= AR \cdot SB \, \Longleftrightarrow \, \frac{AR}{CS}=\frac{RB}{SB}=3/4.$$

And finally,

$$\frac{AT^2}{CT^2}=\frac{AR^2}{CS^2}=\frac{9}{16}\, \Longrightarrow \frac{AT}{CT}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Answer (score 2):

By bisector theorem:
$$\frac{m}{n}=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$m^2=cAR=c(c-BR)$$
$$n^2=aCS=a(a-BS)\rightarrow$$
$$\frac{c(c-BR)}{a(a-BS)}=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$$
$$\frac{c-BR}{a-BS}=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$ac-aBR=ac-cBS\rightarrow \frac{c}{a}=\frac{BR}{BS}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

> - Use the power of the points $A$ and $C$ with respect to the circle;

> - Use angle bisector theorem for angle $\angle ABC$.